# Word VBA using RegEx and Comments

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I am using RegEx with VBA Macros to find matches in a word file as the find function is not sufficient in some cases.
Matches should be marked(working) and a comment should be appllied.
However if i add comments(or comments already exist) the Match.FirstIndex gets thrown of by one for every previous comment.
Comments with the same text counting as one.

Why is that? How to fix it?

Simplified example:

```
Sub Mark_QuestionAndExpressionMarks()
    Dim Match As Match
    Dim Matches
    Dim regEx As New regExp

    regEx.Pattern = "\?|!" 'regex for questionmark or expressionmark
    regEx.IgnoreCase = False
    regEx.Global = True

    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text) ' or ActiveDocument.Content.Text

    For Each Match In Matches
        Call HighlightAndComment(ActiveDocument.range(Match.FirstIndex, Match.FirstIndex + Len(Match.Value)), "Question or Expressionmark")
// problem here as Match is realized correctly but the FirstIndex is off
    Next
End Sub

Sub HighlightAndComment(WordOrSentence As Object, comment As String)
        WordOrSentence.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Call ActiveDocument.range.Comments.Add(WordOrSentence, comment) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it word or Excel? If it's both, how is each involved?

Comment: Word only, no excel

Comment: So, the problem is that the highlight is set on the character before `?` or `!` with the 2nd and following matches, right? This is really strange because the match FirstIndex is calculated correctly.

Comment: Index will be one before for every comment set in the text before the match.

Comment: If there are comments on any part of the text before the appearance of a ? or ! the index will be one too less for every "unique" comment. i expect it to still highlight and comment on all following question or expressionmarks, even if there have been comments on parts of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not profound in regex so I tried a different approach to solve that problem. Hope it helps.

```
Sub Mark_QuestionAndExpressionMarks()

    Dim charsToSearch As String

    charsToSearch = "?!"

    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 1 To doc.Range.characters.Count
        'Check if character is one of the searched ones
        If (InStr(charsToSearch, doc.Range.characters(j)) > 0) Then
             Call HighlightAndComment(doc.Range.characters(j), "Question or Expressionmark")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```